# ngrx - effect for group of actions

Tags: ngrx

i have a store with few actions: play, stop, clear, change
all of the actions have effects and they work great.
my question is, is there a way to create a single effect for this group? if one of this actions is dispatched, i want a separate effect that sends a new action(btnsStateChaned)

i don't want to add my new action in every effect

i want something to replace all the || operators(they don't work as well):

```js
    updateBtnsState$: Observable<Action> = createEffect(() =>
        this.actions$.pipe(
            ofType(gridStateActions.Play || gridStateActions.Stop || gridStateActions.ClearActive || gridStateActions.ChangeVideo),
            map(_ => new gridStateActions.UpdateButtonsState())
        )
    );
```

**UPDATE**

```js
    updateBtnsState$: Observable<Action> = createEffect(() =>
        this.actions$.pipe(
            ofType(gridStateActions.GRID_ACTIONS.PLAY, gridStateActions.GRID_ACTIONS.STOP, gridStateActions.GRID_ACTIONS.CLEAR_ACTIVE, gridStateActions.GRID_ACTIONS.CHANGE_VIDEO),
            map(_ => new gridStateActions.UpdateButtonsState())
        )
    );
```

this is working, still, i would like to know if there is a better way

Answer (score 2):

that's exactly the way as you specified in your question:

```js
ofType(
  gridStateActions.GRID_ACTIONS.PLAY,
  gridStateActions.GRID_ACTIONS.STOP,
  gridStateActions.GRID_ACTIONS.CLEAR_ACTIVE,
  gridStateActions.GRID_ACTIONS.CHANGE_VIDEO,
),
```

and there's no other official way to do it.